# Which DSLR is better for an entry-level photographer (2013)?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, nikon, pentax

On my question, I would really appreciate if you can give me pieces of advise on whether which DSLR I'm going to pick. I'm really a total beginner. Please consider the following factors:

1. Ease of use.
2. Available lenses.
3. **Brand Name** (Canon, Nikkon, Pentax, Sony)
4. Image Quality
5. Effects (Built-in)

I have read about the following cameras but I would love to get reviews from the true experts such as yourselves:

- Canon Rebel T5i (EOS 700D)
- Nikon D5200
- Pentax K-30
- Sony SLT A57

Thank you

**P.S.
I put the year 2013 because as we all know that previous questions regarding camera comparison between brands is only applicable for their own respective year(generation).**

Comment: Regardless of the year (2013), you are still asking a question that has been answered widely at PhotoSE. Start with this one if you have not already. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23428/what-is-a-good-cheap-camera-for-new-photographer-who-wants-to-take-pictures-of-p

Comment: Please be more specific. Like the 4 brand/model I mentioned.

Comment: Ulfric, these models change, as you say, so this question is very localised, so not really suitable for SE.  We also don't know many things we'd need to know to advise you: your budget, what sorts of photography you might do (landscapes, travel, indoor photos of the kids, fast-moving sports, macro etc).  Also you say you're a total beginner, but have you used a point-and-shoot?  The Sony is aimed more at beginners than your other choices I think.

Comment: Thank you. but let's say I'm aiming for entry to semi-pro level.

Comment: Your question can´t be answered. Which camera is the best choice depends an what you want to shoot (sport, concerts), who your are (good eyssight, child, rich) etc. Its just not the right question format for Stackexchange.

Comment: "Entry-level photographer" is awful broad. You need to tell us in your question what kind of pictures you want to take, and how much you're willing/capable of spending to start out.

Comment: I would rephrase the question, I think, otherwise this question is bound to get closed by the community. Specific questions about what elements to look for based on your shooting desires is probably far more useful in the long run. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for details.

Comment: We've all seen web forums where camera recommendations devolve into flame wars about which brand is best. Somebody's going to swear that Nikon is best this year, and someone else will swear that it's always Canon, and someone else will say that Sigma's Foveon tech makes both irrelevant, and then someone else will tell you that Pentax or Sony provides hidden value, and then either you'll just be more confused than before or you'll pick one based on which ranter sounds better (or maybe based on your own existing biases), leaving a minefield that helps no one. We don't want that here.

Comment: We actually _do_ have a series of questions answers designed to help new users make the decisions you're making, and hopefully avoiding the flamewar scenario. Take a look at [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr) and its answers, and also at the specific other questions I link there, which actually go through your concerns about brand and lenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personal opinion only, but I'm quite fond of electronic viewfinder, so given those four options it would be the Sony A57 for me. One good advice I picked up here in PhotoSE is that you go to a camerashop and try out them all, in the sense of choosing the one that best fits in your hands. These cameras are all quite good, even the Sony, but they are also somewhat heavy and once you go out to do your things with your new camera it will be more fun with the one that is easy to hold.

About the in-camera effects, please don't put much emphasis on that part. There's only so many effects, and far less of those you'd really want to use. And after a while you will grow weary of them and eventually forget there is any in-camera effects at all.

Image quality comes more from the lens than the camera. So now you have to choose the lens first, if IQ is the deciding factor. But as many choises of lenses as there is to choose from, you'll really just find the two or three you like and soon forget about how large or narrow the list of possible lenses there is for each brand.

So, finally you only have the first-mentioned criteria left, *Ease of use*. Well, go to the shop and try the feel of the cameras.