# Is something moving inside a micro four thirds camera when you take a picture?

Tags: micro-four-thirds, mirrorless

I just spent some time playing with a couple of Olympus micro four third cameras and I was surprised that when I took a picture, I felt the body of the camera jerking slightly. That's something I would expect on a SLR, since we have a mirror going back and forth really fast, but why is the same effect happening on a mirrorless camera? What is moving? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, electrons :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All SLDs, other than the [Nikon 1 J1](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/j1), have a mechanical shutter. This is most likely what you hear each time a shot is taken.

*Most* of them use the mechanical shutter at the beginning of the shot and *all* of them use one at the end. The latest models omit the front curtain to improve shutter-lag but that is because they found a way to reliable discharge the sensor fast enough.

On Olympus and Sony SLDs there is also a stabilization system which moves the sensor. It makes a gentle noise throughout the exposure but you won't hear it unless you are in a quiet environment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term SLDs, does it include mirror-less as well as DSLR?

Comment: @J.PabloFernández - I think he meant SLRs. Googling "SLD" turns up nothing.

Comment: SLD is Single Lens Digital. They have interchangeable lens but no reflex viewfinder. This are mostly mirrorless cameras but also translucent mirror ones (SLT). See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/what-does-the-acronym-sld-stand-for

Comment: @Pablo - The term you were looking for is ILC: Interchangeable Lens Camera. This one covers SLRs and SLDs.